# Navigate to other page (Office 365)

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-part, redirect, office-365

I want to navigate from one ASP.NET page to another one (each with a visual webpart)
When I click a button on the first page (in my visual webpart of course), I should navigate to the second page.
But it seems I cant use Response.Redirect(...) in my c# code of the first visual webpart.
Also Server.Transfer cannot be used.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks!
(If it isn't possible to use this, is there another way?)

What **DOESN'T** work:

```
Response.Redirect("url");
SPUtility.Redirect("url")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect
Server.Transfer
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct. None of the above options work in Sandbox.

I got around this issue by using the JavaScript `window.location = "new url"` and then pushing it to the page using the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx

Comment: I'll try this later this week, but I think this could work...

Answer (score -1):

try Response.Redirect("your page url");

so, something like this should work for you:

protected void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Response.Redirect("your page url");
}

Comment: I said I can't use this... I guess because I'm in a sandboxed solution

Comment: can you post the code that you currently have?

Comment: No, because I don't have any. I've only got an empty function. When I try to use Response.Redirect("<my url>"), It doesn't accept the Response.Redirect as valid command

Comment: you can try SPUtility.Redirect()  or, HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect

Comment: As I thought, Response.Redirect is in the System.Web namespace. I had imported the assembly, namespace already, so I guess this is being blocked by a sandboxed solution

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect throws an error:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at System.Web.HttpResponse.End() at ...

Comment: For the SPUtility, I can import the namespace, assembly. But I cannot use the Redirect on SPUtility. I guess again sandboxed solution :(